# Java regular expression matches unexpectedly

Tags: java, regex

How come the following returns true?

```
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,12})").matcher("passworD12345678").find();
```

Shouldn't it fail on `(?=.{8,12})` since its length is outside of the range?

Comment: `.{8,12}` matches 8 to 12 characters anywhere in the string.

Comment: @mustaccio What changes are needed to validate the string based on the length and other requirements (contains upper case and digit)?

Comment: @Pshemo You sure? It compiles for me.

Comment: Simply do this `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=^.{8,12}$)` This way you are required to match the beginning and end of a string for the 8-12 character requirement :)

Comment: @Shashank Could you elaborate on why the `^` and `$` are necessary? Shouldn't `find()` match the whole string (which is a substring) and see if it's within 8 to 12 characters long?

Comment: @Glide I don't think `find()` is getting the whole string. When you do `match()` on that string, you only match with substrings that are 8-12 characters long. `find()` returns true because it is iterating through the matches which are substrings like "passworD1", "assworD12", etc. `match()` does not match the whole string.

Comment: to easily check to see if your pattern matches, I highly recommend using regex101.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`find()` doesn't check if entire string can be matched by regex, `matches()` does. `find` simply tries to find any substring which can be matched by regex. Also `(?=.{8,12})` check if there is place which has 8 to 12 characters after it. So either add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` `$` in your regex representing start and end of the string like

```
Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[A-Z])"
                + "(?=.*[a-z])"
                + "(?=.*[0-9])"
                + "(?=.{8,12}$)").matcher("passworD12345678").find();
```

or use `matches()` with this regex

```
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])"
                + "(?=.*[a-z])"
                + "(?=.*[0-9])"
                + ".{8,12}").matcher("passworD12345678").matches();
//                 ^^^^^^^ we can't use look-ahead because we need some part of regex 
//                         which will let regex consume all characters from string
```

Comment: What happened to all the comments?

Comment: @Glide - probably nothing to say. Why the bounty?

Comment: @sln I suspect that these comments ware reason of the bounty. They ware like step-by-step introduction lesson to some regex mechanism allowing OP and other readers understand this answer better, so I find it strange that they ware removed. This lesson was quite long (12-16 comments about ^ $, look-around, zero-width) so I decided to not place it directly in answer which was probably mistake since it was removed now :(

Comment: @sln Pshemo is right. The responsiveness and patience Pshemo provided in the comments were exemplary. I wish I could get back the comments.